# Load UserControl Style in every time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control inside aspx page.
my problem is everytime that the page get reloaded (even when the IsPostBack if false) the user control style load again.
how can i solve this?

Comment: there's nothing. its a userControl and Load it inside aspx with LoadControl().

Answer (score 0):

you can dynamically loads the user control in (if ispostback false)

Please try this.

if(!ispostback)
 { UserControl userControl = this.LoadControl("virtualPath");
PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(userControl);
}

And put a PlaceHolder to hold the userControl